# How is the Numpy "fill" method implemented?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

You see two equal arrays is created using Core Python methods and using Numpy methods:

```
from time import time
import numpy as np

a = [3] * 100000
b = np.array(a)
```

The question is that how is that possible that Numpy is faster than Core Python methods in filling process:

Fill:

```
st = time()
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = 0
et = time()
print "Core Python need %f seconds" % (et-st)

st = time()
b.fill(0)
et = time()
print "Numpy need %f seconds" %  (et-st)
```

Result:

```
Core Python need 0.014000 seconds
Numpy need 0.000000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.013000 seconds
Numpy need 0.000000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.014000 seconds
Numpy need 0.000000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.013000 seconds
Numpy need 0.001000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.013000 seconds
Numpy need 0.001000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.013000 seconds
Numpy need 0.000000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.013000 seconds
Numpy need 0.000000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.014000 seconds
Numpy need 0.000000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.013000 seconds
Numpy need 0.000000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.013000 seconds
Numpy need 0.000000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.013000 seconds
Numpy need 0.000000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.014000 seconds
Numpy need 0.000000 seconds
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Core Python need 0.014000 seconds
Numpy need 0.000000 seconds
>>>
```

Comment: interesting question. Maybe arrays and lists are not the same thing? +Core Python has to go through the loop. `Fill` probably does it in a more efficient way,

Comment: Arrays are contiguous block of memory, list are not. It is easy to fill a contiguous block of memory with a specific value, especially `0`, it is much "harder" to fill a list with the same value.

Comment: @Holt Do you mean: In python a 100,000 elements list may use different small blocks in different positions of memory, while it is a single big block for arrays? Any specification for that?

Comment: @EbraHim Yes, each element will use its own block (probably not far in memory thanks to python's memory management). See https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented - A python list is a contiguous array **of references**, the object are not contiguous, only references to them.

Comment: Doing `a[:] = [0]*len(a)` may be faster than the explicit `for` loop.

Comment: @EbraHim If you are familiar with languages such as C/C++, you can see numpy arrays as "array of `int`s", and python list as "array of pointers to `int`".

Comment: @Bakuriu I think creation is different from filling, so I can't compare times, right?

Comment: @EbraHim But `a[:] = ...` **fills** the list `a`. It *also* creates an array that is used to fill `a`, but `a` is modified in-place. To be clear, if you have `a=b=[1,2,3]; a[:] = [3,2,1]` then you'd have also `b == [3,2,1]`. It's different from `a=b=[1,2,3];a = [3,2,1]` where `b` would remain `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: Isn't it as simple as: `C loops >> python loops` (in terms of speed) ?. Looping in python is slow... when you call numpy's `fill` method, it is calling a C implementation that fills contiguous blocks of memory with the same number, which is much faster to do in C than python.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the time to convert `a` into a numpy array, then the core python methods take about the same amount of the time.

```
In [14]: %%timeit
   ....: a = [3] * 100000
   ....: for i in range(len(a)):
   ....:     a[i] = 0
   ....:
100 loops, best of 3: 9.94 ms per loop

In [15]: %%timeit
   ....: a = [3] * 100000
   ....: b = np.array(a)
   ....: b.fill(0)
   ....:
100 loops, best of 3: 9.47 ms per loop
```

Comment: I agree that it is a good idea to initialize a and b - before execution %%timeit. However - you should compare the python-loop with np.fill() function - the result of this compare is: python-loop is 1000 times slower than np.fill() operation

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 'arrays' may have the same values, but they aren't stored in the same way

```
a = [3] * 100000
b = np.array(a)
```

`a`, as a list, consists of a 100000 pointers to the number `3` (stored else where in memory).  `a[i]=0` changes one of those pointers to the location of `0`.  Your loop changes each of those pointers, at interpreted Python speed.

A good chunk of the time is just spent in the looping mechanism:

```
In [139]: %%timeit a=[3]*100000
     ...: for i in range(len(a)):a[i]=0    
100 loops, best of 3: 13.4 ms per loop

In [140]: %%timeit a=[3]*100000
     ...: for i in range(len(a)):pass 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.86 ms per loop
```

`b` is a new structure, a numpy array.  Creating that from the list takes some time:

```
In [142]: %timeit b=np.array(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop
```

But once created, `numpy` can perform a number of tasks at fast, compiled code speed.  `b.fill` is one of those.

```
In [144]: %%timeit b=np.array(a)
     ...: b.fill(0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 74 µs per loop
```

You can't readily see how the `fill` is done because the code is compiled.

`b` is an object with attributes like shape and strides, and a data buffer.  In this case the buffer starts as a `c` array containing many `3`s (not pointers to a `3`).  `numpy` `fill(0)` performs a fast `c` operation, writing `0` to each of those bytes.

So there are 2 key differences

- the storage (a list of points v a list of values)
- interpreted v compiled code.